# Propagator in massless scalar field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, integration

Suppose we have the following Lagrangian:

$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} \phi \Box \phi + V(\phi)$,

where $\Box = \partial _ {\mu} \partial ^ {\mu}$ and $V$ is the interaction term. We use the $(-+++)$ signature.

Is it true that the propagator is
$- \frac{i}{k ^ 2 - i \epsilon}$?

If we used the $(+---)$ signature, would the propagator be
$- \frac{i}{k ^ 2 + i \epsilon}$ or $\frac{i}{k ^ 2 + i \epsilon}$?

I am not particularly sure about the sign in each case. Could someone please explain?

Comment: The sign of the $i\epsilon$ has nothing to do with the metric signature; it's just there to shift the poles to facilitate contour integration. You don't even need it in evaluating Feynman diagrams, usually.

Comment: JamalS, thanks very much for your comment but I am referring to the sign of the propagator, not the sign of $i \epsilon$.

Comment: Well, you changed the sign of the $i\epsilon$ if you check your equations, so I thought you had doubts about that too. Regarding the overall sign, I think it's $+$ for both.

Comment: A rather interesting problem. For a generic theory we typically have $\mathcal{L} = K + V$ or something to that affect; flipping the convention for the metric signature results in $\mathcal{L} \mapsto -K + V$, the kinetic term has its sign flipped while the interaction term is unscathed by the transformation. It's not obvious to me that the resulting propagator must even be related up to sign.

Comment: I think the answer is eventually that the sign will flip from $- \frac {i} {k^2 - i \epsilon}$ to $\frac {i} {k^2 - i \epsilon}$ since under the metric signature transformation we obtain $\mathcal{L} \mapsto - \mathcal{L} + 2 V(\phi)$; and since $V$ here is more or less arbitrary we just obtain a sign altered Lagrangian.